# Destroy all spree current_order data and line_items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am working on Rails Spree developing a new functionality that erase the current user cart and all of the elements there.

Currently I am using this code and it's done the work, but I feel that I could do it better.

```
def buy_same_order 
    current_order = current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true)
    current_order.item_total = 0
    current_order.total = 0
    current_order.item_count = 0
    current_order.line_items = []
    current_order.save!
end
```

Anyone know how to improve it? Maybe there is a spree method that to specificily that!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a method that to exactly that

```
cart_empty_service.call(order: current_order)
```

I found here

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v4.3.0.rc1/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb#L40